# Segmented Circle Interaction in html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry, imagemap

I have a segmented Circle like the one below, and I would like to be able to interact with it by clicking on the numbers.

[image: Segmented Circle]

I've created an imagemap, hooking the area-tags with onclick-events, but I would like the background behind the number I click to change from white to blue.

I'm not locked in on the imagemap idea, so if there are any other approaches to achieve this then I'm open for those suggestions too.

Comment: Try to use SVG in order to do this ! It will be easier

Comment: Do you have any examples of an svg approach for something like this?

Comment: Not really, do some research on google there is a lot of SVG tutorial.